# Project Euler problem 2: sum of even Fibonacci numbers

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to solve [Project Euler problem 2](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=2) in Java:

```
public class Euler2 {

public static long GenerateFibonacci(int term) {

    long sum = 0;
    long fib = 0;
    long f1 = 0;
    long f2 = 1;
    if (term <=1) return term;
    for (int i = 1; i <= term; i++) {
        fib = f1 + f2;
        f1 = f2;
        f2 = fib;
        if(fib %2 ==0)
            sum += fib;         
    }
    return sum;

}

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n = 100;
        long result = GenerateFibonacci(n);
        System.out.println("The sum of the even Fibonacci numbers is: "+result);
    }
}
```

When *n* is small I get the right answer but for bigger values I get the wrong result. What's the problem here?

Comment: If you are trying to solve PE 2, it only needs Fibo under 4mil.

Comment: Thanks, i completely misread the problem statement. i guess this code is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int` is limited to 32-bit accuracy, `long` to 64-bit.

When you exceed the limit by adding numbers whose result is larger then the bit limit, they "roll over" and you lose the most significant bits from the result of the addition - essentially, they are "rounded" to 32/64 bits.

Here's an example of rolling over:

```
int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // 2147483647
i++; // -2147483648
```

Roughly speaking, each fibonnacci number is double the previous one, so roughly speaking you can only handle in the order of 64 iterations using a `long` as the total.

Comment: but value of n is 100 which is well within the limit.

Comment: @Jonathan, 100 is, but the 100th fibonacci number is not.

Answer (score 2):

The largest long value in Java is 9223372036854775807. Adding 1 to this value produces -9223372036854775807 because the integer values in most programming languages come from a finite set of values, and when you reach the highest value and add one the sequence "wraps around" to the beginning.

If you need to go outside this range, which you will to get the 100th Fibonacci number, use BigInteger.

Comment: You are right with your suggestion of using BigInteger for the 100th Fibonacci number. For the problem Jonathan tries to solve, namely the second Project Euler problem, using long is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The sum is greater than `Long.MAX_VALUE`. You're correct (in your comment to @Bohemian) that `n` is less than that limit, but it is rather surprising how quickly this simple series can grow. The 100th Fibonacci number, for example, is 354224848179261915075. The sum of the first 100 is a 20 digit number, just to give you a feeling for the scale you're dealing with.

Comment: The sum is actually under 5 million.  The rapid growth in the series means that you only have a small number of terms in your sum, and most of those are much smaller than 4 million.

Comment: Based on the PE problem, yes; not based on OP's stated problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use BigInteger, you can also use the fact that every third Fibonacci number is even.

```
public static BigInteger sumOfEvenFibonacci(int term) {
    BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
    BigInteger f1 = BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger f2 = BigInteger.ONE;
    for (int i = 1; i <= term; i+=3) {
        BigInteger fib = f1.add(f2);
        sum = sum.add(fib);
        f1 = f2.add(fib);
        f2 = fib.add(f1);
    }
    return sum;
}

System.out.println(sumOfEvenFibonacci(100));
```

prints

```
1213946614199987541226
```

Answer (score 1):

You can improve efficiency of 'GenerateFibonacci' with following code.  This should be a comment but I can not format the code in comment, I am doing this in answer,

```
public class FibUtil {

//Constants used in equation to calculate nth fib term
private static final double fibA=1/Math.sqrt(5);
private static final double fibB=(1+Math.sqrt(5))/2;
private static final double fibC=(1-Math.sqrt(5))/2;

public static double getNthFibTerm(long n){
    return fibA*(Math.pow(fibB, n)-Math.pow(fibC, n));
}
```

}

Further, based on euler 2 problem statement, you can just add only nth terms which are multiples of 3. I leave 'why' to you.

Answer (score -1):

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package evenfibonaccisum;

import java.math.BigInteger;

/**
 *
 * @author blades of Aragon
 */
public class EvenFibonacciSum {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        long a=0;
      long b=1;
       long fib=1;
        int i=10;
        long sum=0;
        while(fib<=4000000){
        fib=a+b;
        a=b;
        b=fib;
           if(fib>=4000000){
           break ;
           }
           else{

               if(fib%2==0){

               sum=sum+fib;

               }


           }

        }
         System.out.println("sum of even Fibonacci "+sum);  






        }



    }
```

Comment: Code dumps without explanation are rarely helpful. Also, whole programs are rarely good answers. Please try to answer the *specific question* being asked.

Comment: @Floegipoky *We don't want to see your boilerplate comments and extraneous whitespace.*... while it's easy to understand what you mean, note that this can be expressed in a more polite manner.